# Any WSGI middleware to make HTTP redirect on specific status code?

Tags: pylons, wsgi, middleware

I'm using Pylons and want to add some middleware to it so that it catches **401 status codes** and makes **HTTP Redirect (302)** to Signin page.

I know there is built-in StatusCodeRedirect in Pylons that acts in a similar fashion, but it does not produce HTTP redirect, and rather redirects *internally* (this is what I do not want).

Is there any existing middleware to add, or any generic middleware that can be easily modified to make HTTP redirects on specific status codes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally.
I've implemented my own middleware class that uses *call_wsgi_application* helper function of *pylons.util*

```
from pylons.util import call_wsgi_application

class StatusCodeHTTPRedirect(object):

    def __init__(self, wsgi_app, codes, redirect_to):
        self.app = wsgi_app
        # Transform codes to str for comparison
        self.codes = tuple([str(x) for x in codes])
        self.redirect_to = redirect_to

    def __call__(self, environ, start_response):
        status, headers, app_iter, exc_info = call_wsgi_application(self.app,
            environ, catch_exc_info=True)

        if status[:3] in self.codes:
            start_response('302 Found', [('Location', self.redirect_to)])
            return []

        start_response(status, headers, exc_info)
        return app_iter
```

Hope this will help someone

Answer (score 1):

This should get you pretty close i didn't test it though but it's loosely based on something I wrote that I am using so tweak as necessary.

```
from webob.dec import wsgify


class Catch401AndRedirect(object):
    """
    responds to 401 redirects to signin page
    """

    def __init__(self, app, signin_url):
        self._app = app
        self._signin_url = signin_url

    @wsgify
    def __call__(self, request):

        response = request.get_response(self._app)

        if response.status_int == 401:
            response.headers["Location"] = self._signin_url
            response.status_int = 302
        else:
            return response
```

edit: forgot to mention this solution requires webob, but since you are using pylons already, you have that dependency.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a complete authentication & authorization library for Pylons. The two most popular are: [AuthKit](http://authkit.org/) and [repoze.who](http://static.repoze.org/whodocs/). They already implement what you want to do.

If you don't want to use an existing library, you can write a custom middleware. It is simply a Python callable `f(environ, start_response)` which processes request data kept in environ. Look into `config/environment.py`.